# Prevent heading from becoming a new slide in a beamer created from markdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc, beamer

I want to create a Beamer slideshow from Markdown using Pandoc. I want all sentences starting with a `#` to start a new slide, EXCEPT for one. How can I do this?

````
    ---
    title: Introduction to Markdown.
    ---

    # Introduction to Markdown
    Markdown is easy to learn. 
    This is how you create headings in Markdown.
    Code: 
    ```
    # Heading Level 1
    ## Heading Level 2
    ### Heading Level 3.
    ```
    Output:
    # Heading Level 1
    ## Heading Level 2
    ### Heading Level 3.
````

I do NOT want `# Heading Level 1` to start a new slide. Can someone please help me ?

Comment: What should `# Heading Level 1 ` do instead?

Comment: not 100% sure what you want, but have you seen https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#structuring-the-slide-show

Comment: I want `#Heading Level 1`  to give me the phrase "Heading Level 1" with it's size as  the size of the first level heading.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50901682/10451245 (i.e., add to YAML header: `header-includes: 
- \AtBeginSection{}`

Comment: @mavericks, thank you. After reading that answer, I think we should set slide_level to 4. Then #,##,### will NOT start a new slide. We can use #### whenever we need to start a new slide.This will work since I am not using headings starting with ####. I do not know how to mention slide_level: 4 in **markdown**, I only know this works in **RMarkdown**.